# Have a navigation bar on right in order

Tags: html, css

I've an issue with the order in a navigation bar to recreate the Google page with a proper order.

I tried  ***flex-direction: row-reverse;***  but it changed nothing.

I try this:

```html
<style>
    .navbar li{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        list-style-type: none;
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a>Gmail</a></li>
            <li><a>Images</a></li>
            <li><img src="/images/app.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="/images/icone.jpg"></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Please next time provide code as a text, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `.navbar li` to `.navbar ul`. The problem is that you are trying to set the `li` elements as flex containers. But since they don't contain anything, it's not doing anything. Instead, each list *item* is getting floated to the right, which naturally reverses their order. Note, however, that you'll probably still want `margin: 10px` to remain on the `li` elements. Here is a modified example:

```css
.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: right;
}

.navbar li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul>
  <li><a>Gmail</a></li>
  <li><a>Images</a></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32"/></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/32"/></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are editing the **li** not the **ul**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the styles on the ul and not the `li` elements:

```css
.navbar ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```